# OleDbCommand not returning results vs SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, oledb

I'm trying to change my program from an `SqlConnection` to an `OleDbConnection` but I've hit a little block.

My program works as expected using `SqlConnection` but I can't get it to work with `OleDb`.

My program reads the results of a stored procedure (XML), sends it to a web service, then stores the results in a table.

I'm having issues with reading the XML from the stored procedure.

Here's my code for the first part:

```
public static bool BuildXml()
{
    using (OleDbCommand buildXml = new OleDbCommand("usp_BUILD_RISKCALC_XML", SqlOleDbConnection))
    {
       buildXml.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       try
       {
           OleDbDataReader reader = buildXml.ExecuteScalar();

           while (reader.Read())
           {
               SendXml = reader.GetString(0);
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             WriteLog(ex.Message, 101);
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an `InvalidOperationException` the text of which reads

> Specified cast is not valid

For `reader.GetString(0)`.

I am 100% sure the stored procedure is working as I have tested using an `SqlConnection` as well as running in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What type is `SendXml`? The obvious answer is that it's not a `string` - the type returned by `reader.GetString(0);`

Comment: Earlier in the class there is `private static string SendXml, ReceiveXml;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be;

```
public static bool BuildXml()
{
     using (OleDbCommand buildXml = new OleDbCommand("usp_BUILD_RISKCALC_XML", SqlOleDbConnection))
     {
          buildXml.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          try
          {
               object value = buildXml.ExecuteScalar();
               SendXml = Convert.ToString(value);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               WriteLog(ex.Message, 101);
               return false;
          }
     }
}
```

The code  `buildXml.ExecuteScalar()` returns an object. So casting it to an `OleDbDataReader` will end up in the `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, the value of `SendXml` after conversion is "System.Byte[]". You can see the output of the storled procedure [here](https://gist.github.com/robbiewoods05/c24c0097ca5fc338bd28)

Comment: What type is `SendXml`?

Answer (score 0):

[`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) return type's is `object` and you can't convert it to `OleDbDataReader`. When you have used `ExecuteScalar` means that you are sure that you want to return only one value from your stored procedure. You don't need `OleDbDataReader` just try following:

```
SendXml = buildXml.ExecuteScalar().ToString;
```

Comment: Implementing your answer gives the same problem above... the value returned is literally "System.Byte[]".

Comment: @robert.woods...Could you post the `usp_BUILD_RISKCALC_XML` too?